# How to handle questions about other sites or services?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

For example, consider this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/32747433/477563

To me it's clear that the linked question may not be answerable.  First of all, there's no way we can even replicate the issue, and second of all, this is more of a question specific to a particular site/service (in this case, GoDaddy).

I reviewed the potential closure votes but none of them fit quite right:

- "**Off Topic -> Belongs on Super User**" doesn't fit because it's not really about "about general computing hardware and software" because it's related to hosting and server configuration.
- "**Off Topic -> Belongs on Server Fault**" doesn't fit because even though GoDaddy deals in hosting, only certain aspects of the hosting server are available for the user to modify.  Because of this, the user isn't a "professional server- or network- administrator", they're simply a customer.
- "**Off Topic -> find a book/tool/library/tutorial or other off-site resource**" somewhat applies, but the question isn't asking *for* a book/tool/library/etc, it's asking for help *with* an off-site resource.
- "**Off Topic -> Why isn't this code working?**" doesn't fit because there simply isn't code.  It does mention being reproducible, but this issue doesn't appear to involve code in any way, only configuration and administration.
- "**Off Topic -> Cannot reproduce/typo**" doesn't quite fit because a resolution to the problem could "help future readers"

Should these kinds of questions be closed?
If so, what would be the correct closure reason for a question like this?

I feel like the example question should be directed to that specific site's support, not StackOverflow, but there's not a closure reason for that.

---

I've stumbled across another question that fits this theme:
[When publishing to shinyapps.io, Error: cannot open the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32747898/477563)

Comment: You are always free to choose the last resort option, to explain why you think the question is OT. The cases are rare, this validly applies, but that's why it is there.

Comment: FWIW, I recently vtc'd [this GoDaddy support question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665346/flask-and-sqlite-hosting-on-godaddy-linux-servers) with "This question appears to be off-topic because it is a customer support request, not a question about a programming problem. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-suppo%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Brt-for-your-favorite-company) for more information."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can always choose a custom close reason when you're 100% sure it is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

In the custom close reason explain why it is off-topic and if you see fit provide guidance for how to proceed.

In the [autocomment-script](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments) the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room uses this generic reason:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

I'm not 100% convinced if that fits here but I share it as an example.

You're always free to suggest an alternative site if you're familiar with that site but make sure you don't migrate crap that way and link to their How to Ask page or [on topic page](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) so the OP can verify the question will fit there. As an alternative suggest to post on meta using the tag [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation)